# .htaccess redirect only one level from site root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to map some direct requests to a custom script:

```
somesite.com/getfile/file_name.xxx
somesite.com/getfile/type1/file_name.xxx
somesite.com/getfile/type2/file_name.xxx
somesite.com/getfile/type3/file_name.xxx
```

To accomplish this task I've created an .htaccess with these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^getfile/(.*)/(.*) /script_path/getfile/file.php?pn=$2&type=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule  ^getfile/(.*) /script_path/getfile/file.php?pn=$1 [L,NC]
```

Everything seems to work fine, but if I call a url like this:

```
somesite.com/test_path/other/getfile/test.php
```

this url will be redirected to the `file.php` script!

I need that only the path that starts with getfile immediatly after the domain name to be sent to the script.

```
somesite.com/getfile -> need to be redirected
somesite.com/test_path/other/getfile/ -> must not be redirected
```

site folder structure

```
/
|_www
   |_serverRootFolder (the .htaccess file here, this is the apache serverRoot is www.somesite.com/)
   |_script_path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(.*)/(.*)` are going to match as far to the right as they can. To match only the ones immediately after the domain, instead of `(.*)` which is anything, use `([^/]+)` which means "not-slash" so it will only go to the next slash. I also added `$` on the end, to say there is nothing else following these.

```
RewriteRule ^getfile/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /script_path/getfile/file.php?pn=$2&type=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^getfile/([^/]+)$ /script_path/getfile/file.php?pn=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! perfect solution to my problem!